# Ecto query retrieve all posts along with the most recent comment

Tags: mysql, sql, elixir, ecto

**Note: I am using MySQL 5.7.**

I have two tables named Post, Comment

```
  schema "posts" do
    field: id, string
    field :title, :string
    field :slug, :string
    field :active, :boolean, default: true
    timestamps()
  end

  schema "comments" do
    field: id, string
    field: post_id, string
    field :title, :string
    field :body, :string
    field :email, :string
    field :meta, :map
    field :active, :boolean, default: false
    timestamps()
  end
```

I am using `Ecto` for the database queries in `Elixir`. Currently, I am having the issue of trying to get all the posts in the database, and the most recent comment for those posts, if available. E.g:

```
Post 1 ──── post1__last_comment_id 
         
Post 2 ──── post2__last_comment_id      

Post 3 ──── nil
```

I have tried `join_left` on `post.id == comment.id`, but that returns all the comments related to the post not just the most recent one.

I tried also `grouping_by comment.post_id` and get the max `id`, while that worked, that is not the desired solution as there is a requirement for it to be based on `date` rather than `id` of the comment.

I looked up how to do it, while I found few solutions for raw SQL queries, I could not find any similar things for Ecto, and could not figure out how to convert it from SQL to Ecto.

Is it possible to be done using Ecto?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a lateral join for this and Ecto supports this.

There's an example in the Ecto documentation that handles your usecase. See here https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3

Below is the example in the docs adapted to what you want.

```
Repo.all from p in Post, as: :post,
           join: c in assoc(p, :comments),
           inner_lateral_join: latest in subquery(
             from Comment,
             where: [post_id: parent_as(:post).id],
             order_by: [{desc: :inserted_at}],
             limit: 1,
             select: [:id]
           ), on: latest.id == c.id,
           preload: [comments: c]
```

Comment: I tried the proposed solution and I am getting this MySQL error:` **(Ecto.QueryError) join ':inner_lateral' not supported by MySQL in query.`

Comment: Yes, MySQL does not support lateral joins. You should look into window functions, these are supported by MySQL afaik. They can give you the same results.

Comment: After doing this, I got the following error:

** (MyXQL.Error) (1064) (ER_PARSE_ERROR) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY post_id ORDER BY start_date DESC) AS row_numberFROMcomment’ at line 1`

I looked up what could cause this error, and I believe it might have to do with MySQL version being 5.7 (not supporting window functions).

If that is the case what other ways I could solve this problem without updating the MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

`distinct` should work for this purpose:

```
last_comment = from c in Comments, order_by: [desc: c.id], distinct: c.posts_id

q = from p in Posts,
  preload: [comments: ^last_comment]

Repo.all(q) 
|> IO.inspect
```